# What type of controller should I use to represent a complex object which is not a (persisting) model?

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing a *calendar application*, which will need to display *events* by month.

While I'll need to create objects to represent the calendar months, I take it that these these `CalenderMonth` objects should **NOT** be '`models`' (in `Ember` terminology), since the `CalendarMonth` objects won't persist to the server (whereas the `Event` objects will). Instead, the `CalendarMonths` will be `'objects'`, build with a `CalendarMonth 'class'`, **extending** `Ember.Object`

So then, what sort of *controller* do I use as a proxy to the (frequently changing) `CalendarMonth` object? A (`vanilla`) controller? An `ObjectController`? An `ArrayController`?

`ObjectController` seems like the way to go, since it really is my intention for the the controller to act as proxy to a single object. I think I'm only thrown by the fact that in the corresponding route object, I'd be assigning the `CalendarMonth` object as the controller's *MODEL*. When, it's not a model, it's just an object.

Put another way, my question is:

Is it bad practice to assign an `Ember object` which is **NOT** a model to an `ObjectController's` `'model'` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not bad practice to use a normal JS object as a controller's model/content. All that matters is how the view is going to render the model. If you're only going to display a single event at a time, or a single month for all events in that month, then the `ObjectController` is your best bet.

An `ArrayController` is used for when you want to loop round your model/content in the controller and display each item in the view. I don't think you should worry too much about what controller you should use, it will become pretty obvious which one you want as soon as you decide how to create your view.

When Ember talks about using a `Model` for your controller, you can use your own Ember Object if you wish and then reference it in the controller, but it doesn't matter if that is a natural JS object or Ember Object. A controller sees both just fine.